# How to change a value of an object form its key value pair and add this new item to the same object iteratively?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and I like to change a value from the key value pair and this changed value should be added to the same object iteratively using JavaScript

Eg

The input array

```
let arrayObject = [
  {
    "obj": {
      "fruit": "apple"
    }
  },
  {
    "obj": {
      "fruit": "orange"
    }
  }
]
```

The expected output is as

```
let arrayObject = [
  {
    "obj": {
      "fruit": "apple",
      "fruitToUpper": "APPLE"
    }
  },
  {
    "obj": {
      "fruit": "orange",
      "fruitToUpper": "ORANGE"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You can map over the array and for each object try returning the new object with the added property?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) - The input is an array of objects.

Comment: @Andreas thats why I gave object name as arrayObject for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) over array and add `fruitToUpper` prop in object.

```js
let arrayObject = [{
    obj: {
      fruit: "apple",
    },
  },
  {
    obj: {
      fruit: "orange",
    },
  },
];

const result = arrayObject.map((o) => {
  o.obj.fruitToUpper = o.obj.fruit.toUpperCase();
  return {
    obj: {
      fruit: o.obj.fruit,
      fruitToUpper: o.obj.fruit.toUpperCase(),
    },
  };
});

console.log(result);
```